# Zonal statistics (and other tools) will not output all records in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.3, zonal-statistics

Using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop, whenever I use zonal statistics, only about 90-95% of the records actually show up in the results. The remainders are blank though, if I navigate to that polygon, there is data present.

I've tried doing this in and out of geodatabase environments, with different shapefiles and rasters as my inputs, and still the same thing. It just seems to 'max out' in some way and not return all of the records. Often, the number of records returned on the same calculation is different. The same things happens if I use the Spatial Analyst 2 toolset, or an independent toolset I downloaded meant to calculate zonal statistics for overlapping polygons.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify; you are trying to use zonal, when your zones are overlapping polygons? An image and the tool's definitions might help to further understand.

Comment: Some of the loss may be accounted for in vector/raster conversion. But without some specific examples of results, screenshots, or more description about your data and the exact tools/steps/inputs you are using, we can't offer much help.